# Product attribute combinations generation in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office, udf

I have a table which contains 13.931 rows and 2 columns, the first column is SKU's, second is Options (Size, Colour, etc..);

- **SKU Option**
- 0001 Size:S
- 0001 Size:M
- 0001 Size:L
- 0001 Size:XL
- 0001 Colour:Red
- 0001 Colour:Blue
- 0002 Size:S
- 0002 Size:M
- 0002 Size:L
- 0002 Colour:Navy
- 0002 Leg:G

and goes on like this. What I need to do is generate every combination of these options **(there are 7 option types in total; some SKU's has 2 types some has 4, some non)** within SKU's, so it'll be like this;

- **SKU Option**
- 0001 Size:S;Colour:Red
- 0001 Size:M;Colour:Red
- 0001 Size:L;Colour:Red
- 0001 Size:XL;Colour:Red
- 0001 Size:S;Colour:Blue
- 0001 Size:M;Colour:Blue
- 0001 Size:L;Colour:Blue
- 0001 Size:XL;Colour:Blue
- 0002 Size:S;Colour:Navy;Leg:G
- 0002 Size:M;Colour:Navy;Leg:G
- 0002 Size:L;Colour:Navy;Leg:G

I can seperate Option column into 2 for option types and option values if it makes it easier.

My question is: Is it doable using macros? Because it is going to be a huge pain if I manually do these.

Comment: `My question is: Is it doable using macros?` Answer: Yes, most likely.  Stack Overflow is not a code for me service.  Use array or dictionary and lots of loops.

Comment: Although not the same, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36824503/2923617)'s a very similar question. It might put you on the right track.

Comment: I just notice that the link I posted was actually your question! Please put in some effort! Starting from the answers provided there, you should be able to figure it out or at least give it a try. Come back here when you run into a specific issue with your own solution and everyone here will be more than happy to help.